# What is the URL should be used while connect AWS glue with Snowflake

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

What is the URL should be used while connect AWS glue with Snowflake

```
"sfURL" : args['URL'],
"sfAccount" : args['ACCOUNT'],
"sfUser" : args['USERNAME'],
"sfPassword" : args['PASSWORD'],
"sfDatabase" : args['DB'],
"sfSchema" : args['SCHEMA'],
"sfWarehouse" : args['WAREHOUSE'],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/) and [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Use-AWS-Glue-With-Snowflake) which talks in detail about connecting Snowflake with AWS Glue. From [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#executing-ddl-dml-sql-statements) link the link URL you should be using is as shown below which contains account and domain of snowflake.

```
"sfURL" -> "<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com"
```